# Error con decimales en clausula Insert

Tags: c#, sql-server

intento hacer un `INSERT` desde un proyecto c# i me pasa los decimales con comas, por lo que en SQL se interpretan como separación de valores.
La solución es hacer primero un `parse` a `string` y un `parse` a decimal en la base de datos al insertar, o hay alguna forma más sencilla?
Cabe decir que cuando me llega el valor a la clase, llega con punto, es al asignarlo en una variable de tipo decimal que lo sustituye por una coma.
Saludos y gracias.

```
 foreach (Order order in Lorders)
            {
                Guid lOguid = Funcions.creaGUID(order.id.ToString());
                cap = new Corder.Cabecera();
                cap.idDocumento = Funcions.creaGUID(order.id.ToString());
                cap.CodigoCliente = order.customer_id.ToString();
                cap.CodigoEmpresa = int.Parse(GlobalVar.Empresa);
                cap.EjercicioDocumneto = int.Parse(GlobalVar.Ejercicio);
                cap.Domicilio = order.billing.address_1 + order.billing.address_2;
                cap.Provincia = order.billing.country;
                cap.FechaDocumento = order.date_completed;
                cap.NumeroDocumento = int.Parse(order.number);
                cap.TipoPagoContrato = order.payment_method;
                cap.ImporteLiquido = order.total;
                cap.IdProcesoIME = lOguid;
                cap.MovIdentificadorIME = lOguid;

                cabeceras.Add(cap);
                string query = $"INSERT INTO {taules._Cabecera} (IdDocumento,CodigoCliente,CodigoEmpresa,EjercicioDocumento,Domicilio,Provincia," +
               $"FechaDocumento,NumeroDocumento,TipoPagoContrato,ImporteLiquido,IdProcesoIME,MovIdentificadorIME) VALUES ('{cap.idDocumento}',{cap.CodigoCliente},{cap.CodigoEmpresa}," +
               $"{cap.EjercicioDocumneto},'{cap.Domicilio}','{cap.Provincia}','{cap.FechaDocumento}',{cap.NumeroDocumento},'{cap.TipoPagoContrato}',{cap.ImporteLiquido},'{cap.IdProcesoIME}','{cap.MovIdentificadorIME}') ";
           }
```

El problema està en `cap.ImporteLiquido = order.total;` `order.total`, me devuelve el valor con punto tipo **15.05**, pero en el string de la consulta tengo **15,05**.

Comment: Mejor si nos mostras como estas haciendo todo, asi podemos decirte como hacerlo mejor... asi solo no queda claro, agrega tu codigo

Comment: Perdona, ya edité la pregunta, gracias.

Comment: no interpoles un string, usa un comando al cual le pases parametros para evitar todo este problema (y los que vas a tener con las fechas)

Comment: ¿Perdona gbianchi, a que te refieres?

Comment: La respuesta es lo que te dice Luis, espera a que la complete...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basado en lo que describes, estás creando/pasando los parámetros a SQL como `string`.

Dependiendo de cómo esté configurado tu ambiente, en tu sistema operativo, los valores numéricos van a ser formateados.

Para solucionarlo, especifica el tipo de dato del parámetro en el SQL command.

Mas informacion aqui:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Aqui va un ejemplo utilizando el SQL Command Builder para ayudarnos a generar los parametros y los SQLCommand por nosotros.

```
namespace Console
{
    class Program
    {       
        static void Main()
        {
            var Lorders = new List<Order>();
            // ...llena la lista de ordernes...         
            try 
            {
                string connectionString = "connection-string";
                using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    // El "SELECT" es solo para obtener la metadata de la tabla y los campos.
                    var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(
                           "SELECT IdDocumento,CodigoCliente,CodigoEmpresa,EjercicioDocumento,Domicilio,Provincia, FechaDocumento,NumeroDocumento,TipoPagoContrato,ImporteLiquido,IdProcesoIME,MovIdentificadorIME " +
                           $"FROM [{taules._Cabecera}]",
                           conn
                    );
                    // Crea instancia de Command-Builder para facilitar la generacion de comandos SQL.
                    SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
                    builder.QuotePrefix = "[";
                    builder.QuoteSuffix = "]";

                    foreach (Order order in Lorders)
                    {
                        // Pasando "true" para auto-generar los parametros con los nombres de los campos en la tabla.
                        var inserCmd = builder.GetInsertCommand(true);

                        // Pasando los valores a los parametros.
                        insertCmd.Parameters["@IdDocumento"].Value = Funcions.creaGUID(order.id.ToString());
                        insertCmd.Parameters["@CodigoCliente"].Value = order.customer_id;
                        insertCmd.Parameters["@ImporteLiquido"].Value = order.total;
                        // Completar los demas parametros...

                        // Ejecuta el comando.
                        insertCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                   }
                }
            }
            catch(SqlException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: Podrias explicar bien esta respuesta, como crear un command, como pasar parametros.. la solucion es por aca, pero tu respuesta no le explica a OP que hacer

Comment: El enlace que pase en mi respuesta, es la documentacion de Miscrosoft .NET SQL Command. Ahi puedes ver varios ejemplos de como crear un SQLCommand y pasar los parametros con los tipos de datos correctos.

Comment: Mejor que la respuesta sea completa y de ejemplos, ademas de llevar a la documentacion.. por favor mira [answer].

Comment: @gbianchi Gracias, por la observación...extenderé mi respuesta con un ejemplo, pero la documentación está bien clara y presenta muy buenos (y variados) ejemplos, que le permitirán a quien hace la pregunta profundizar más sus conocimientos, no solo dar una respuesta rápida para ganar un par de puntos.

Comment: En realidad la mayoria de las preguntas no existirian si primero pasaran por la documentacion.. pero por eso, pedimos respuestas lo mas completa posibles...

Comment: Leyendo en la documentación veo que a parameter se le suele pasar el tipo de dato, en cambio en tu ejemplo no lo haces, ¿no es necesario en este caso?. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: @Miquel Linea `builder.GetInsertCommand(true)` genera los parametros, con el nombre de los campos, por ti con el tipo de dato correcto utilizando la metadata de la DB. Esta es solo una forma de hacerlo... puedes tambien crear la instancia del SQLCommand tu mismo y definir los parametros de forma manual, pero es mucho boilerplate IMO.

Comment: @Luis,perdona, basandome en tu codigo y usando el `SqlCommandBuilde`, me salta una excepcion:
 **System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'El nombre de objeto 'dbo.TmpIME_CabeceraDocumento' no es válido.'** 
Esa tabla existe, y el select que le paso al `SqlAddapter` funciona sin problemas, algo no hago bien. 
También me he encontrado que al dar valor a lo parametros del SqlCommand:  `insertCmd.Parameters["@CodigoCliente"] = order.customer_id;` Me muestra el error:
**no se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'decimal?' en "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter"**
Me puedes ayudar porfavor ?

Comment: Aaaahh... por por esto `[{taules._Cabecera}]`... lo que provoca que el string resultante sea `[dbo.TmpIME_CabeceraDocumento]`, en vez de `[dbo].[TmpIME_CabeceraDocumento]`. Elimina los corchetes o modifica el nombre de la tabla en la variable. En el segundo... estas tratando de asignar el valor de un `Nullable` type... debes asignar el valor almacenado en el nullable type: `insertCmd.Parameters["@CodigoCliente"] = order.customer_id.Value;`

Comment: Un poco mas de informacion sobre `Nullable` types: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-nullable-types

Comment: Eliminando corchetes solucionado, pero el
`insertCmd.Parameters["@CodigoCliente"] = order.customer_id.Value;`, genera el error :`No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'int' en 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter` Parece que `insertCmd.Parameters["@CodigoCliente"], CodigoCliente` es de tipo `Varchar()` en la tabla, `order.customer_id`, es un entero. pero probando también :
`insertCmd.Parameters["@CodigoCliente"] = order.customer_id.Value.ToString();` obtengo el mismo resultado, es como si estuviera esperando un objeto de tipo `SqlParameter`, pero hacer un casting tampoco resulta.

Comment: Si, realmente hubo una omisión de mi parte. Cuando haces `insertCmd.Parameters["@parameterName"]`, eso devuelve el objeto parámetro... por lo que el valor se debe asignar a la propiedad `.Value`. Actualice el ejemplo con la corrección.

Comment: Ahora lo entiendo, gracias, por tu ayuda @Luis.

Comment: @Luis, usando el `CommandBuilder` no me respeta los `defaults` de la tabla  y me obliga a entrar todos los parámetros, ¿no hay manera de poder usarlos ?

Comment: Si, el `CommandBuilder` no ayuda en esa parte... lo que puedes hacer es probar listando solo los campos que quieres insertar en el `SELECT` para generar parámetros solo para esos campos. Si aun tienes el mismo problema, deberás cambiar la implementación y crear un SQLCommand con el `INSERT` y los parámetros de forma manual. Puedes ver como crear el `INSERT` de forma manual aquí: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12939501/insert-into-c-sharp-with-sqlcommand

Comment: Si, dando valor a todos los campos del SELECT no hay problema. ¿Me recomiendas que construya los parámetros de forma manual, o que controle esos campos sensibles a no tener valor con condicionales ?

Comment: Esos son detalles de implementación que debes evaluar. Te recomiendo tratar de mantener un balance entre dogma (seguir el manual al pie de la letra) y "practicalidad/pragmatismo" (implementar lo que funciona mejor para resolver el problema).